# Missing number if no missing number, add max number + 1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want a sql query: 
I have list of number and want to find out the FIRST missing number if there is no missing number in the list then give me the next available number

for example I have a column data 1,2,4, that means I need three which is a missing number and If i have 1,2,3,4 then i need number 5. Please help thanks

Comment: Looks like please do my homework!!

Comment: I tell my 2 year old daughter most days: "Not: I want... I would like"

Comment: It would be useful to understand the reason behind this requirement. Are you trying to fill the sequence of an autonumber field in a database?

Comment: Guys take it easy. I am not that good in English. Also I tried but didn't put it here as there is lots of queries I worked on. But still I can say sorry if I made a mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.Number) + 1 AS MissingNumber 
FROM dbo.TableName t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableName t2 
    ON (t1.Number + 1 = t2.Number) 
WHERE t2.Number IS NULL
```

However, this is a race condition, the first wins. Normally you should not fill gaps.  If it's a key column you could use an [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column with auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Note the +1, so to include the next number if the sequence is "complete",
-- And the isnull(,0) to handle the "empty table" case
declare @m as int = (select isnull(max(id), 0) + 1 from yourtable)

-- Sequence 1...@m of numbers
;with t as (
    select 1 x
    union all 
    select x + 1
    from t
    where x <= @m)

-- Find the minimum missing numebr
select min(x) from t where not exists (select 1 from yourtable where id = x)
```

Where `yourtable` is the table you want to find the missing numbers from and `id` is the column of which you want to find the missing numbers.